# Sails.js server bootstrap

Tags: node.js, cron, sails.js

I'm currently working with Sails.js and have hopefully a simple question for you. In this small project I work with auctions which end on a specific date.

My question is how can I make a "cron job look a like" which checks every auction end time.

I tried the following code:

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new cronJob('1 * * * * *', function(){
    console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, null);
```

The problem is when multiple users go to the page of the auction, multiple cronjobs will execute. Is there a way to make a bootstrap file in Sails.js after the start of the server or something like that?

Comment: Why don't you just use `crontab` instead of making it part of Sails itself?  Where are you inserting this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There sure is: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/config.bootstrap. See `bootstrap.js` in your `config` folder.

That said, I'm not sure if using crons is the best way to handle it (resource consuming and inefficient), I would try organizing the code in an event-based manner instead.

Comment: Wow that I missed that in the documentation. Need to drink more coffee haha thanks! But how can I build this event driven because an auction is stored in the database and only accessable by the controller? Or im i completly stupid right now?

Comment: Well, I meant if you can load a list of auctions with end dates, you can just set up a queue of events to be fired on a specific time, right? And your listeners would do the thing, you wouldn't need to run a cron every second for that.